# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.176.43.99:3306

Tags: javascript, database

I'm trying to use my biz.nf database in node.js programme but I'm getting a connection refused error.
Error:
[Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZVDM.png)

Code:

```js
const {createPool} = require("mysql")

const pool = createPool({
  host: "fdb27.biz.nf",
  port: 3306,
  user: "3723359_coolbot",
  password: process.env.pass,
  database: "3723359_coolbot"
})

pool.query('SELECT * FROM FirstTable', function (err, result, fields) {
 if(err) return console.log(err)
 console.log(result) })
```

Comment: 3306 is the default port. 3308 is possibly a typo?

Comment: the odd thing is ... you set `port: 3308` but the error states it's port 3306 that is refusing the connection

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, it's a typo here. Let me correct it

Comment: @JaromandaX corrected

Comment: According to nmap, 185.176.43.99:3306 is closed

Comment: any idea on how to access that?

Answer (score 0):

Most hosts disallow connecting directly to a database from a remote system. Are you certain your hosting provider allows this and has enabled access from all points on the internet? This is generally considered a security concern so it's unlikely they allow this by default.

To connect from an external application as you seem to be doing here, you'll probably need to relay your connection through some intermediary service such as an SSH or VPN tunnel or by implementing a custom API from the server. Another solution could be to run the application directly on your host's servers which would be able to connect directly to the database server since it's already on your host's network.